# How do I get the old procps-ng top(1) layout back (pre-3.3.10)?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, top

Since updating to procps-ng 3.3.10 my `top(1)` looks like this:

[image: Not so sane...]

Instead of:

[image: ...somewhat sane]

Not only are these colours annoying & offensive, I can't get it to sort as the "old" `top(1)` (`O` no longer works, and can't get `f` or `F` to work).

Since I have more useful & interesting things to do with my allotted time of existence on this planet than figuring all of this out, I would prefer to just get the "old" layout back (which works just fine), without compiling it myself (so I can just use my system's package manager).

The [`NEWS` file](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps/source/3a66fba1e934cbd830df572d8d03c05b4f4a5f1e:NEWS) says:

```
* top offers new startup defaults, plus ./configure --disable-modern-top
```

The wording of *"startup defaults"* suggests there is a way to configure top in a way that's the same (or very similar) to the "old".

I've already looked at `top/top.h`, and the below settings are different, but I don't know how to get the originals (defined by `ORIG_TOPDEFS`) back through either a set of switches, or a config file.

```
#ifdef ORIG_TOPDEFS
#define DEF_WINFLGS ( View_LOADAV | View_STATES | View_CPUSUM | View_MEMORY \
   | Show_HIBOLD | Show_HIROWS | Show_IDLEPS | Show_TASKON | Show_JRNUMS \
   | Qsrt_NORMAL )
#define DEF_GRAPHS2  0, 0
#define DEF_SCALES2  SK_Kb, SK_Kb
#define ALT_WINFLGS  DEF_WINFLGS
#define ALT_GRAPHS2  0, 0
#else
#define DEF_WINFLGS ( View_LOADAV | View_STATES | View_MEMORY \
   | Show_COLORS | Show_FOREST | Show_HIROWS | Show_IDLEPS | Show_JRNUMS | Show_TASKON \
   | Qsrt_NORMAL )
#define DEF_GRAPHS2  1, 2
#define DEF_SCALES2  SK_Gb, SK_Mb
#define ALT_WINFLGS (DEF_WINFLGS | Show_HIBOLD) & ~Show_FOREST
#define ALT_GRAPHS2  2, 0
#endif


#ifdef ORIG_TOPDEFS
#define DEF_FIELDS  "¥¨³´»½ÀÄ·º¹Å&')*+,-./012568<>?ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[" RCF_PLUS_H
#else
#define DEF_FIELDS  "¥&K¨³´»½@·º¹56ÄFÅ')*+,-./0128<>?ABCGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[" RCF_PLUS_H
#endif
```

Comment: Not what you're asking for, but being unhappy with `top` might be a good opportunity to abandon it in favor of `htop`.  It's default look is much closer to "modern top" (in fact probably inspired it?) but it's easy to configure (F2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set options you want (see help with `?` key), then save them with `W`

So, to get something like old top back, press `zV1W`

[image: expected result]

Mine `~/.toprc` currently looks like this:

```
top's Config File (Linux processes with windows)
Id:i, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=1.500, Curwin=0
Def fieldscur=¥&Kš³Ž»œ@·º¹56ÄFÅ')*+,-./0128<>?ABCGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=192820, sortindx=18, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=1, graph_mems=2
    summclr=1, msgsclr=1, headclr=3, taskclr=1
Job fieldscur=¥Š¹·º(³ŽÄ»œ@<§Å)*+,-./012568>?ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=163124, sortindx=0, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=2, graph_mems=0
    summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem fieldscur=¥º»<œŸ¿ÀÁMBNÃD34·Å&'()*+,-./0125689FGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=163124, sortindx=21, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=2, graph_mems=0
    summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr fieldscur=¥Š§šª°¹·ºÄÅ)+,-./1234568;<=>?@ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghij
    winflags=163124, sortindx=3, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=2, graph_mems=0
    summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=3
Fixed_widest=0, Summ_mscale=2, Task_mscale=1, Zero_suppress=0
```